# How do I find out what kind of encryption this is and how to decode it?

Tags: encryption

0xugm5chUcCO+KqKV58YwSwh3kMOHDFju8wtSIuZCbBAAFJaHkYDloRXz9qLEz3unGiAwZEyTvlRhnt6slOFZQ==

Im wondering how to figure what this is and how to decrypt it.

Comment: Doesn't look like encrypted text. Looks like base64 (which is simply a form of encoding). If it is truly encrypted with a good algorithm you shouldn't be able to tell what it was encrypted with. You MIGHT be able to make a few educated guessed based on block size, though...but that's besides the point.

Comment: Download Hashcat and learn how to use it :D

Comment: Nice try, everyone, this is taken from my post on se7ensins.com about a tool to decrypt certain files in the game Grand Theft Auto V. The post was made to help people with knowledge, not to have people asking other people how to crack it.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, seeing a `==` or a `=` suffix is a strong indicator that the data has been Base64 encoded (but not mandatory). You haven't specified whether the encoding was done for the purpose of the post.

In any case, the underlying data is binary. Without an [entropic test kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test) and a [file format analyser](http://www.safer-networking.org/products/filealyzer/), a unencrypted binary file with uncommon or no metadata can not be ruled out.

If it is encrypted, you enter **very** difficult territory. If you know the key, you need an application that can try out the 100s of common encryption formats. If you don't know the key then you need a supercomputer cluster and specially designed GRID computing tools unless the key is trivially small. And the difference between trivially small and insanely large is only a handful of bytes.

Comment: So basically, pull the other leg - it has bells on it.